# $_GET not working in yii2 framework

Tags: yii2

Accessing this url: `http://sampledomain.com/controller/action/1?t=test&p=1`

I tried this:

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->request->get());
```

And this:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

The result is:

```
array(0) {}
```

But when I tried to use the `$_GET` in a regular php script, it displays the those variables.

Is there anyone here experience this also? Thanks.

Comment: `Yii::$app->request->get()` is just a wrapper, Yii way to access `$_GET` PHP superglobal array. It should work. Post more code, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: check your url. probably it should be `http://sampledomain.com/controller/action?t=test&p=1`

Comment: Do you have some special url management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it's the configuration on the server. This is what I'm doing.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

It should be like this

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

Comment: As I said the problem is not related with Yii.